# Redes de virtualbox me generan problemas en mi red fisica al iniciar windows 10

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Estoy conectado a internet mediante Ethernet, pero el virtual box me provoca problemas al conectarme al internet cada vez que arranco el sistema, esto lo soluciono ejecutando el solucionador de problemas mostrándome una lista de redes disponibles, la ethernet y las de virtual box, selecciono la ethernet y me soluciona el problema arrojándome que el error fue por "no tiene una configuración de ip valida".

Si desinstalo virtual box dejo de tener ese problema, **¿Cómo puedo configurar para que me reconozca la ip de ethernet cada vez que inicio el sistema sin tener que desinstalar virtualbox?**

En el administrador de hardware en la seccion de redes tengo:

- Realtek PCIe
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #1
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #4
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #5
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #6
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #7
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #8
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #9
- Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #10

Y en el virtual box tengo:

- Un version de linux instalada
- La version de genymotion (emulador android)
- Windows 10 para virtualbox

Comment: en las propiedades del adaptador, tcp/ip, avanzado -> metric , le quitas el automático y le pones un número mas bajo para que tenga prioridad

Comment: Sospecho que virtualbox se esté iniciando (como servicio) al arrancar el sistema, debes quitarlo de la lista de servicios que cargan al arrancar (**no me preguntes como, hace años que no uso windows** pero cuando lo usaba podía decidir qué servicios arrancaban al iniciar el sistema) y cargarlo sobre demanda. Yo uso virtualbox en Linux, pero **existe sólo cuando lo necesito** nunca arranca con el sistema.

Comment: @aloMalbarez me sirvio tu solucion.

Comment: @quevedo También me sirvió tu solución pero me deja desactivado el servicio de virtual box y si lo abro me marca error, trate de levantar el servicio y me marcaba deshabilitado. Lo que hice fue entrar a msconfig y en la pestaña de servicios deshabilite el de virtual box y reinicie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema suele ser que windows "busca internet" en cada una de las interfaces de red y sólo el "solucionador de problemas" es capaz de encontrar la interface correcta ( sucede también si hay varios adaptadores wifi o varios de red física y windows no puede inferir la interface correcta ), el orden de búsqueda está dado por el `InterfaceMetric` de cada interface ( cuan costoso es enrutar una petición por ese interface ).

La forma de cambiar la `InterfaceMetric` via GUI:

> En las propiedades del adaptador ethernet, tcp/ipv4 , avanzado -> metric , le quitas el automático y le pones un número mas bajo para que tenga prioridad

La forma de cambiar la `InterfaceMetric`  via PowerShell es con [`Set-NetIPInterface`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipinterface?view=win10-ps) para lo cual primero consultamos cual es el identificador de la interface que queremos cambiar mediante [`Get-NetIPInterface`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipinterface?view=win10-ps)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetIPInterface

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily InterfaceMetric Dhcp     
------- --------------                  ------------- --------------- ----     
19      Ethernet 3                      IPv6                       35 Enabled  
17      VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2 IPv6                       25 Enabled  
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6                       75 Disabled 
16      Local Area Connection* 10       IPv6                       75 Enabled  
19      Ethernet 3                      IPv4                       35 Enabled  
17      VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2 IPv4                       25 Disabled 
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4                       75 Disabled
```

En este caso la interface que quiero con mayor prioridad ( menor costo ) es la que tiene index 19, así que el comando para cambiar el metric quedaría:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 19 -InterfaceMetric 15
```

Comment: Adenda: Windows tiene el **horrible** hábito de dejar como gateway por defecto la __última__ interfaz que se habilita. Por diseño, Ethernet se levanta primero y las de Virtualbox, que se levantan con el servicio, suben después. Por eso hay que avisarle cuál debe usar con el valor de métrica

Comment: Investigando en otras partes, tambien es importa mencionar que no es bueno tomar el numero 1 ya que ese lo reserva generalmente para loopback, por lo que se recomienda utilizar de 2 para arriba, siendo 2 el de mayor prioridad